# How to express orthogonal basis of space spanned by some vector in a correct way?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, article-writing

I have a series of vectors, suppose ${a,b,c,d,e}$. These vector span a space.
$span \{a,b,c,d,e\}$.
I have the orthogonal base of the space, supposed called $u,v,x,y,z$.

How can I express the relationship between two sets of vectors in mathematical expression?

I want something like the following, but I do not know how to express that correctly.

$(u,v,x,y,z) ... =span\{{a,b,c,d,e\}}$

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there something wrong with "$\{u,v,x,y,z\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the subspace $\text{span}\{a,b,c,d,e\}$"?

Comment: Sir, I do not know why is wrong with the {u,v,x,y,z}, it is calculated from Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization, it is the orthogonal bases of the space spaned by abcde.

Comment: No, what I meant to ask is "what is wrong with simply expressing the relationship using plain words?" like in my previous comment. I don't think there is a particular mathematical notation for "this is an orthonormal basis."

Comment: Aaa, yes. I get your idea, sir. I write ${u,v,x,y,z}=span \{{a,b,c,d,e\}}$ in the paper. My teacher asks me to find the correct notations for that. I have no idea, just come here ask for help.